# Way to follow or receive notification on page update for end user?

Tags: wagtail

We have a need for our end-users to be able to click a "watch" button or something similar to get update notifications when page contents are updated.

Is there a feature or plugin for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism for this, but you could build one by defining a "Subscription" model to keep track of which users are watching a given page, and adding a listener for the [`page_published` signal](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/signals.html#page-published) that sends the notification to those users.